# Unable to connect external postgresql database to Heroku

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, plotly-dash, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy a Dash app onto Heroku that is connected to an external PostgreSQL database. I've tried to use the `heroku-postgres` addon but I don't quite understand how that works, and I think it also won't have enough space for the data I need. I currently have an external PostgreSQL database I'm using and I've gone through the steps to attach/detach/config:add the new `DATABASE_URL`.

Every time I deploy I run into this error (more of the error code in the image):

```
Error fetching data from PostgreSQL table could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

[image]

I've set up my Config Vars such that the `DATABASE_URL` is `postgres://user:password@host_ip:port/database_name`

and in my code I'm connecting to the database via a `.env` file that looks like this:

```
# Development settings
user="user"
password="password"
host="ip"
database="postgres"
```

Also, I saw somewhere that this might be useful to check `ps -ef | grep postgres` and the output of that shows the correct database connection, but the output of `pg_lsclusters` shows nothing.

Please let me know if I can provide any more info. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not trying to connect to a remote Postgres.  It's trying to connect locally to a Postgres server on the same computer.  That suggests your URL is not being read.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about that? I thought by attaching the DATABASE_URL of my remote database it would work.

Comment: If you do `echo $DATABASE_URL`, does it show your URL?

Comment: Nothing shows up when I use `echo $DATABASE_URL` but `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a <your_heroku_app_name>` shows me the DATABASE_URL I have in the original post (same as the DATABASE_URL I see in the Heroku site).